# Anchor tag with display block not taking space of its parent container

Tags: css

I have a parent `div` which contains two elements, a `small` tag and an `a` tag. Currently, we can see that the parent wrapper has a height and width.

Now, I need to remove that `small` tag whilst keeping the space that the `a` tag would take up. I've tried applying both `display: block` and `display: inline-block` to the anchor tag but as soon as the `small` tag is removed, the parent wrapper collapses.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/jghdewqv/

```css
.wrapper {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

a {
    background-color: firebrick;
    display: block; /* Also tried inline-block */
    float: right;
}

small {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <small>Left text here</small>
    <a href="#">Some link here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is because of the float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, You need a **clearfix** CSS code here, You can learn about it from Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/clearfix/

Here is an example after using clearfix css.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.wrapper::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

a {
  background-color: firebrick;
  float: right;
}

small {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#">Some link here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah! So the issue is the fact that the anchor tag is floated right! This is some older CSS that I'm dealing with so perhaps I can switch that to flexbox instead.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't collapse it just doesn't have a height `height:20px;`

https://jsfiddle.net/jghdewqv/

```css
.wrapper {
    background-color: lightblue;
    height:20px;
}

a {
    background-color: firebrick;
    float: right;
}

small {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Some Link here</a>
</div>
```